# SSDT Data comparison, login failed

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

When ever I try to proceed to the second step in the comparison, it displays a message saying that it cannot connect with the login I provided (sqlAuth not win).

**Note A**: It will let me run queries and even do a schema comparison, but no luck with data comparison.

**Note B**: localhost works fine.

Versions:

Remote:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)    Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
>     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on
>   Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Local:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (RTM-CU14) (KB3158271) - 12.0.2569.0 (X64) 
>     May 27 2016 15:06:08    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Express
>   Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 10586: )

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: The generic "login failed for user".

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, except schema comparisons are not working for me.

Comment: @StuartQ I haven't as it is now seems to work okay for some bizarre reason. anyway, if you haven't, try to give a shot to James answer as it seems to lead to a useful link supported by the SSDT team.

Comment: It's now working for me.  I attempted a reinstall (was already on the latest version), but it may simply have been restarting VS that did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

There have been a number of connection-related fixes in the [latest SSDT 16.5 release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx). I just worked through a similar issue with a partner building SSDT demos, and updating to latest resolved issues in Data and Schema compare for SQL Authentication with them. Specifically, there were issues where the "Remember Password" checkbox wasn't preserved which was causing issues, so you may need a one-time action to enter the password so that it's re-saved correctly.

**Disclosure:** I work on the SQL Server tools team.

Comment: Thanks kevin. I think I used that version. if it was available by the 26th then I have. but unfortunately it did not help. the strange thing is that after using some external tool to compare schemas, SSDT was working fine again.

Comment: it fixed my connection issue on VS 2015

Answer (score 1):

I'm having similar issues with SQL Server auth.

Possible answers are listed on this similar question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102605/azure-sql-database-login-failed-for-user-in-application-but-works-fine-in-ssm

Which links to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/74d2b7f0-09f2-4ef3-935b-e0a1e0e8fb82/schema-compare-target-unavailable?forum=ssdt